# UILabel with subview

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, addsubview

For some reasons I have to have a UILabel with a custom background view which I wanted to achieve by [label addSubview:backgroundView].

The background renders fine, but the Labels text does not appear.

What I can't do is using the background color with a pattern image.

Comment: What is your question? Can't you use `UIImageView` with `UILabel` on top?

Comment: The question is: why does the labels text not show up, while the subview displays correctly and how to avoid it. What I can't do is change the setup. The UILabel has to be at the top level and there must be a way to have a background view without using a UIView or the patterned background

Comment: addSubview adds over the current view, in your case label, so that text is displayed, simply closed backgroudView. Join to the question about a UIImageView of the previous comments

Comment: "addSubview adds over the current view" suggests that sending it into the background would solve the problem, which it does not. ImageView is not an option.

Comment: sending it into the background doesn't solve the problem becouse backgroundView is singular subview of label and label with its text lies below all its subview. You is not gonna do it, but if you really do not want to post UIlabel on something, you can try to put a form on it with a superview property: [label.superview insertSubview:view1 belowSubview:label];

Comment: Mhm. I liked the idea, but it does not work as intended. Now the background view is not showing up (params look good)

Comment: Whats about label.backroundColor? Is it clearColor (if it was created programmatic backroundColor is white by default)?

Comment: Yup, checked that (even tried insertSubview:aboveSubview). For now I made a UIView wrapper - which is not the preferable solution but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've read some more posts I had to re-consider and in the end use a subclasses UIView. Not preferable as said in my post and comment, but finally working.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[label insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Edit:

I found something not sure how it would work tho. Try using the backgroundColor property.
Something like:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:yourImage];
```

Great, I was late with this again...

Comment: You seem to be quick in dishing out negative ratings. I messed up the verification a few times and when I finally managed it Andreas had already answered.

Comment: live is rough. costs me a view points as well - but keeps the post clean.

Answer (score 1):

Really an old thread but I faced the same issue, and figured my solution might help someone (Using PureLayout and swift 4) and programmatically adding the views.

Sample usage in your viewController:

```
 private lazy var labelContainer: UIView = {
        // Configure the label:
        let labelView = UILabel.newAutoLayout()
        labelView.text = label
        labelView.textColor = .red
        labelView.textAlignment = .center
        labelView.numberOfLines = 1
        
        // Configure your custom background view (UIView for this sample)
        let bgView = UIView.newAutoLayout()
        bgView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        // The combined view with "padding":
        let paddingVertical = 12
        let paddingHorizontal = 16
        let padding = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: paddingVertical, left: paddingHorizontal, bottom: paddingVertical, right: paddingHorizontal)
        let view = labelView.wrapperOnTopOf(bgView: bgView, insets: padding)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
}()
```

Now you can just add this view and setup the constraints programmatically as you like.

For this implementation you need the UIView extension .wrapperOnTopOf which is implemented like:

```
extension UIView {
   /**
    * Function to wrap the current view in a UIView on top of another view
    * - UIView
    */
   func wrapperOnTopOf(bgView: UIView, insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero) -> UIView {
       let container = UIView.newAutoLayout()
       bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
       container.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)
       container.insertSubview(self, at: 1)
       // Let this view determine the size of the container:
       self.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: insets)
       return container
   }
}
```

Comment: I'll up this one since it uses a new technique as well as Swift.